# What is the best way to maintain xpaths in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

For now I'm just maintaining it in '.ini' file and accessing via 'configparser'. But the problem is, when we are working with some big applications with so many pages in it, it's very difficult to make any changes.

```
[login]
login_window=//h4[text()='Login']
username_input=//input[@name='username']
password_input=//input[@name='password']
login_button=//input[@value='Login']
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping XPATH externally is a good approach, but XPATH is time-consuming, it lacks performance and as you found out is hard to maintain.

Instead of that use CSS_SELECOTRS, CLASSNAME, or ID - those are rarely changed and it keeps your tests updated with new UI changes. Also - use Page Object pattern - you can keep UI pages mapped in classes and each field will be defined by a selector, it's easier to keep tracking changes.

eg.

```
username_input=By.CSS_SELECTOR("input[@name='username']")
password_input=By.CSS_SELECTOR("input[@name='password']")
login_button=By.CSS_SELECTOR("input[@value='Login']")
```

here is a nice introduction for [PO pattern](https://blog.testproject.io/2019/07/16/develop-page-object-selenium-tests-using-python/)